# What does のに at the end of a sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

Does it have a similar meaning to "が、ので etc." which basically make the sentence "softer" and imply something that isn't stated but that should be obvious to the listener?

Is it something like "though" in English ?

2 examples:

> - 彼が出て行けばいい**のに**。
> - あの建物さえなければ、きれいな景色が見える**のに**。

Comment: Can you post some example sentences that you've seen with this?

Comment: I don't remember any right now, I found this two in another question though. *edited

Answer (score 13, accepted):

のに at the end of a sentence can be rendered as something like "if only it weren't the case that ~"

From your examples:

彼が出て行けばいいのに。 (Aw man, it would have been so good had he gone)

あの建物さえなければ、きれいな景色が見えるのに。 (If only that building weren't there, we could see the beautiful scenery)

A~ いいのに is a fairly common usage, "would have been good if [only] ~A"

It usually reflects a state of regret or longing, or an improvement that can be made on the scene or experience.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what parts of speech in what conjugated forms could directly proceed 「のに」.

Comment: I understand now, thanks. I guess it wasn't the same as  "が、ので ending a sentence then. :p