# what kind/conjugation of verb is used in this pattern?

Tags: verbs, conjugations

In this pattern: Vばいいのに. (literally, it would be good if you ~).

What conjugation of verb should I use here?

Is this correct: お腹空いた時、お食事を食べればいいのに。?

Comment: Related? http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23226/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good for use of "ばいいのに"!
"お食事" is not for eating, stands for breakfast, lunch, dinner ... and Japanese will says as follows
お腹空いた時、何か食べればいいのに。
"何か" is something.